# C Program with Pointer Increment False Values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with the following C Program I am making. The code simply creates a pointer, which is then assigned the address of an integer array. From there, the pointer is given a value and is then incremented. 
The output displays the array name, the array address and the array value. The output works as expected, except the last item in the array has increased by 5, rather than one.

The code is shown below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int numar[4];       //integer array
    int x;              //value for loop
    int *p;             //pointer
    p=numar;            //'point' p to address of numar array (no & necessary as arrays are pointers)
    for(x=0;x<5;x++)    //loop 0-4
    {
        *p=x;           //assign the value of the first item in array to x
        p++;            //increment pointer for next iteration 
    }
    for(x=0;x<5;x++)    //loop 0-4
    {
        //display output of array name, array location and array value
        printf("array[%d] is at address %p with value %d\n", x,&numar[x],numar[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is shown below :

```
array[0] is at address 0061FF18 with value 0
array[1] is at address 0061FF1C with value 1
array[2] is at address 0061FF20 with value 2
array[3] is at address 0061FF24 with value 3
array[4] is at address 0061FF28 with value 8
```

As you can see, the desired value for array[4] should be 4, but it is instead 8.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,

Comment: `int numar[4]; ` but looks like you access index 4 (max valid is 3) therefore you run off the end of the array and invoke undefined behavior. Here come the nasal demons....

Comment: `[4]` means the array has 4 elements

Comment: Arrays are ***not*** pointers.  A (sub-)expression that evaluates to an array "decays" to a pointer to the first element of that array (and so your assignment works), but that's an altogether different thing.

Comment: Stupid mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your code compile, I had to make one change: I added 'int' before 'main', so that the main function could correctly return 0.

The problem is that you have created an integer array of size 4, but you want it to contain 5 items.

```
int numar[4];
```

Means that your array is defined for 4 elements:

```
numar[0]
numar[1]
numar[2]
numar[3]
```

Therefore,

```
numar[4]
```

is undefined.

To fix this, make your array one size larger:

```
int numar[5];
```

The output I get is:

```
array[0] is at address 0x7fff557f0730 with value 0
array[1] is at address 0x7fff557f0734 with value 1
array[2] is at address 0x7fff557f0738 with value 2
array[3] is at address 0x7fff557f073c with value 3
array[4] is at address 0x7fff557f0740 with value 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. A silly mistake on my behalf.

Answer (score 2):

sorry there's no way to make array's indexes begin from 1 so they begin from 0 so if you have an array of 4 elements then the last element is element with index 3 not 4.

in your code you are reading five elements where you only have an array of 4 elements.

```
for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) // iterating five times not 4: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4  
    //....
```

* the worst thing to write to non-elements of an array is to dongle on other variables eg:

```
int a = 0; // initialized to avoid compiler complaining later on
int numar[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3}; // ok
numar[4] = 77; // writing to the fifth element which doesn't belong to numar. as you can see variable a right before numar

cout << a << endl; // a: 77!! where did a get this value? because a is right before numar so element five which doesn't belong to numar was allocated to a
```

in this example we dongled unintentionally on other variables (a) abd the most frustrating thing is that the compiler doesn't complain (we initialized a to 0 )
the result is an error-prone which is in a huge code would look impossible to capture.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the index you are using for your array.

You are creating a 4-element array with `int numar[4]`. This creates array which has valid indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3. **There is no index `[4]` here!**

Therefore, when you are later filling and accessing the array in the `for` loops, you should set them up like this:

```
for(x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
```

`x < **4**`, not `5`. This loop will check indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Your loop accesses element `[4]`, which does not belong to the array.